# Can you install apps in asp.net like in django?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django

I am a python developer. I just started learning asp.net framework. Django supports a thing where you can install an existing app into your project. For example, I could create a calendar app and then use it in a different django project. Does asp.net mvc have anything similar to this?

Comment: Possibly [nuget](http://www.nuget.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NuGet is the package manager for the Microsoft development platform including .NET. The NuGet client tools provide the ability to produce and consume packages. The NuGet Gallery is the central package repository used by all package authors and consumers.`

http://www.nuget.org/

Comment: You can use this from within the Visual Studio IDE, you just search for the app you want and click install.